# Show svg element when its parent becomes visible after display:none

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

in css:

```
.regions-popup{
    display:none;
}
```

html:

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
        <linearGradient id="textgradient10-1" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
                    <stop stop-color="#880e7e" offset="0%"/>
                    <stop stop-color="#e1004b" offset="100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    </svg>

    <div id="regions-popup">
      <h3>
        <svg class="svgtext">
          <text font-size="24" fill="url(#textgradient10-1)" stroke="none">Text one</text>
        </svg>
      </h3>
    </div>
```

later in code:

```
$("#regions-popup").show();
```

The div shows up without text "Text One". How can I make the text render when its needed, or may be render it in the beginning and hide it immediately

Comment: `display-none;` ? or `display: none` ?

Comment: Your code suggests you just have `<linearGradient>` tags in your HTML.  That won't work.  It needs to be in an `<svg>`.

Comment: no i didn't include them, didn't find it necessary. ill edit

Answer (score 0):

From the code you supplied, the SVG has no height defined (or viewbox for that matter). If you add that, the text appears.

Equally, the `<text>` has no positioning values and I'm unsure what the defaults would be...probably `x=0 y=0` in which case the bottom edge of the `text` would be just off the top of the SVG 'box' I made the y-value  equal to 24px and it seems to position the text correctly.

Yep: [**Source**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html#positioning-text)

> The position of the text is determined by the x and y attributes of the  element. The x-attribute determines where to locate the left edge of the text (the start of the text). The y-attribute determines where to locate the bottom of the text (not the top).

I notice that the SVG seems to have a default width for which I cannot determine the origin...but I think that 300px may be a default for SVG.

```js
$("#regions-popup").show();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hidden {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
#regions-popup {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="hidden">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="textgradient10-1" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
      <stop stop-color="#880e7e" offset="0%" />
      <stop stop-color="#e1004b" offset="100%" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div id="regions-popup">
  <h3>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="24px">
    <text x="0" y="24" fill="url(#textgradient10-1)" font-size="24px">Text One</text>
</svg>
  </h3>
  <div>
```